# Ansible - Checking for variable value when using "with_dict"

Tags: ansible, lets-encrypt

I'm currently using a self-build playbook for managing webservers. I've specified the websites that should be created in another file, called sites.yml.

So far, everything is working perfectly. Except, I would like to add Let's Encrypt support to my websites, and here comes the problem.. How?

I'm executing various tasks based on the content of the file sites.yml. But I would like to enable Let's encrypt using a variable per site.

My sites.yml is as follow:

```
sites:
  site1:
    name: site1
    server_name: site1.example.com
    document_root: /var/vhosts/site1.example.com
    environment: staging
    db_name: site1
    db_password: password
  site2:
    name: site2
    server_name: site2.example.com
    document_root: /var/vhosts/site2.staging.sddev.nl
    environment: staging
    db_name: site2
    db_password: password
```

I'd like to just add a variable like `letsencrypt: true` to enable Let's Encrypt, but how do I check for this variable in a with_dict loop? The Letsencrypt tasks should only be executed when the variable is set.

I thought it should be something like this:

```
- name: LETSENCRYPT | Securing websites
  command: --COMMAND FOR OBTAINING CERTIFICATE--
  with_dict: "{{ sites }}"
  when: "site.letsencrypt = true?"
```

Can anyone give me more information for using `when` in `with_dict` loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check [with_dict](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-hashes) documentation. You can use `item.value`:

```
- name: LETSENCRYPT | Securing websites
  command: --COMMAND FOR OBTAINING CERTIFICATE--
  with_dict: "{{ sites }}"
  when: item.value.letsencrypt | default(false) | bool
```